# android - sql server - connection either null or no suitable driver found

Tags: java, android, azure, jdbc, azure-sql-database

My connection java file contains :

```
try {
    Log.i("Login", "Establishing Connection...");
    // SET CONNECTIONSTRING
    Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    Log.i("JDBC","found");
    Connection DbConn = DriverManager.getConnection("<connection_string>");

    Log.i("Login","Connected");
    Statement stmt = DbConn.createStatement();
    ResultSet insert = stmt.executeQuery("insert into UserLogin(username, password) values (admin, admin);");
    ResultSet reset = stmt.executeQuery(" select * from UserLogin ");

    Toast.makeText(this, reset.getString(1), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    DbConn.close();

    // go to newsfeed
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("Error connection","" + e.getMessage());
}
```

When my connection string contains:
 **jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://**, I gets **error in connection :null**,and when it's
 **jdbc:sqlserver://**,         I gets **error in connection:no suitable driver found**.

I'm trying to connect **Android with Azure SQL DB**.

> I've seen **[Question1,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23354129/jtds-android-connect-to-sql-server-error-connection-null)** [**Question2,**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24586935/no-suitable-drivers-found-sql-server-android) [**Question3,**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24950296/android-connecting-ms-sql-server-2008-r2-error-connection-null-eclipse) [**Question4.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36560421/no-suitable-driver-sql-server-jtds)  
>   No Answer.

Comment: It's recommended to add another part between the Android client and the database server. Something like PHP, ASP.NET, Python, etc. Consider a scenario in which attacker reverse engineer your Android client, then he has a direct access to your database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@NiravMadariya, The JDBC connection string with jTDS shoule be `jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://<server>:<port>/<database>`, please see the jTDS FAQ which includes [`URL format`](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/faq.html#urlFormat) and the reason for [`No suitable driver`](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/faq.html#noSuitableDriver) exception.

Note, if you are using the JTDS JDBC driver for Auzre SQL DB, then you will need to add `ssl=require` to the URL of the connection string as like this `jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://<server>:<port>/<database>?ssl=require`.

Meanwhile, using Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server is a recommend way for Azure SQL DB, please see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-develop-java-simple/.